# Java Spring boot app unable to connect to CloudSQL from Google App Engine

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a spring boot app connecting to the Cloud SQL (MySQL 8) in the same project in the GCP.
The app runs fine on the local machine. But the same app is unable to connect to the same database when deployed to the GAE. The GAE deployment is successful & the traffic is set to the latest version of the service.

The database configs are in the application yaml as below:

```
spring:   
  cloud:     
    gcp:       
      sql:         
        database-name: <myDB>
        instance-connection-name: <copied from the cloud sql dashboard>
  datasource:     
    url: jdbc:mysql://<static ip of the database>:3306/<database name>    
    username: <myUsername>     
    password: <myPassword>     
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver   
  jpa:     
    hibernate:       
    ddl-auto: none     
    show-sql: false
```

The error messages are as below:

`"Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure"`

`main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'javax.persistence.jdbc.url', 'hibernate.connection.url', or 'hibernate.dialect')"`

As I mentioned earlier, this code works perfectly fine in the localhost.

I have even tried out the https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-app-engine tutorial which seems working fine, hence I believe all my configs are correct.

Comment: Are you sure the Cloud SQL database accept connections from anywhere? There is no network blocker somewhere?

Comment: Looks like FW rules issue related please make sure to validate that first of you can make use of sql router proxy as well as alternative to legacy sql connections